# React src and public folders missing

Tags: reactjs, npx

I am trying to create a react app. When I run the `npx create-react-app myapp` command, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohsr0.png) is what happens. I know I can ignore the vulnerabilities but the src and public folders are missing in the app folder.
How can I get the missing folders?

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps

1. remove create-react-app

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

2)update npm npx using the following commands.

```
npm update npx
```

and run the final step

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: I tried this multiple times, and still same outcome and the folders are still missing

Comment: try this one `npm install -g create-react-app` and then `npx create-react-app my-app` make sure you remove all `npm cache`

Comment: I tried this too.. no difference

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands as follow :

npm i -g npm

npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npm updates npx

npx create-react-app app-name